# Как допилить toggle и-ый клик на групы?

Tags: vue.js

toggle click между key и item

```js
const ChooseListStudents = new Vue({
  el: '#chooseListStudents',
  data: {
   groups: [
    {1: ['Ivanov', 'Mac', 'Orehov']},
    {2: ['Shobdra', 'Rimar', 'Haguev']},
    {3: ['Slobodinaiuk', 'Shelepko', 'Androshuk']}
   ],
   listStudent: [],
   showlistSt: false,
   addSt: true,
   itemstudent: false
  },
  methods: {
   addStudent(item) {
    this.listStudent.push(item);
   },
   ShowAllGroups() {
    this.showlistSt= true
    this.addSt= false
   },
   showStudent() {
    this.itemstudent=true
   }

  }
 })
```

```html
<div id="chooseListStudents">
 <div v-for="(group, idx) in groups" :key="idx" v-show="showlistSt"> 
  <div v-for="(sub, key) in group" :key="key">
   <h3 @click="showStudent(this)"> Group {{ key }}</h3>
   <div v-for="(item, i) in sub" :key="i" @click="addStudent(item)" v-show="itemstudent">{{ item }}</div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <p>List students!</p>
 <button @click="ShowAllGroups()" v-show="addSt">Add</button>
 <div>
  <div v-for="student in listStudent">{{ student }}</div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: А какой эффект ожидается? Опишите поподробнее.

Comment: При клике на 1 показывается 'Ivanov', 'Mac', 'Orehov'. 

Аналогично на 2, 3. Сначала элементы массивов 1,2,3 не показываються. А при клике на и-ый видим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так получилось.

```js
const ChooseListStudents = new Vue({
            el: '#chooseListStudents',
            data(){return {
                    groups:[
                        {id:1, members:['Ivanov', 'Mac', 'Orehov']},
                        {id:2, members:['Shobdra', 'Rimar', 'Haguev']},
                        {id:3, members:['Slobodinaiuk', 'Shelepko', 'Androshuk']},
                    ],
                    isShow:false,
                    listStudent:[]
            }},
            methods: {
                showGroup(i){
                    return this.groups[i].itemstudent = !this.groups[i].itemstudent;
                },
                addUser(list){
                    this.listStudent.push(list);
                }
            },
            created() {
                this.groups.forEach(element => {
                    this.$set(element, 'itemstudent', false)
                });
            },
        })
```

```html
<div id="chooseListStudents">
            <ul v-for="(group,index) in groups" :key="group.id" v-show="isShow">
                   <h3 @click="showGroup(index)"> Group - {{group.id}} </h3>
                <li v-for="list in group.members" v-show="group.itemstudent" @click="addUser(list)">
                    {{list}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button @click="isShow=!isShow" v-show="!isShow">Add</button>
            <ul v-show="isShow">
                List students!
                <li v-for="lastName in listStudent">
                    {{lastName}}
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: спс Алексей!))))